# Venv is not running the executable from the virtual environment

Tags: python, python-venv

I want to execute an executable called `mod_wsgi-express` in my virtual environment.

When I run `which mod_wsgi-express` it shows me the correct location I want to use, being `/home/robin/.virtualenvs/jspvenv/bin/mod_wsgi-express`.

But when I try to execute mod_wsgi-express, it shows the following error:

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/mod_wsgi-express: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I have python only installed in my virtual env, hence the error, but why is it executing it from `/usr/local/bin/mod_wsgi-express` and not from my venv location?

For the time being I am able to run it with the whole path `/home/robin/.virtualenvs/jspvenv/bin/mod_wsgi-express`, but is there a way to change that?

Comment: Did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: I could have sworn so, but it's working now, thanks ‍♂️
But I'm still wondering why `which` gave me a different path then...